# Facebook SDK I have access only to public data

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with access to data such as email and date of birth. It seems to me that there is something of a token but I am looking for information and I can not see what's going on.Maybe someone will notice an error or met with something similar

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtStatus;
    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    public String email,id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeControls();
        loginWithFB();

    }

    private void initializeControls(){
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        txtStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    }

    private void loginWithFB(){
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.e("Success", "Login");
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name ,email, gender, birthday");

                GraphRequest gr = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                                if (response.getError() != null) {
                                    // handle error
                                    System.out.println("ERROR "+response.getError().toString());
                                } else {
                                    //System.out.println("Success");

                                    String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
                                    System.out.println("JSON Result"+jsonresult);
                                    String resp = String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject());
                                    System.out.println("JSON resp "+resp);


                                }
                            }

                        });
                gr.setParameters(parameters);
                gr.executeAsync();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                txtStatus.setText("Cancelled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                txtStatus.setText("Error " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
```

After you have initalised login button.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#addbutton

Comment: Also take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/overview:
"If your app asks for more than than public_profile, email and user_friends it will require review by Facebook before your app can be used by people other than the app's developers."

Comment: This means that when you need more data than the public instead of the above, I have to apply the `loginButton.registerCallback (callbackManager, new FacebookCallback <LoginResult> ()` ? Instead of `LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()`

Comment: as Gavin Harris mentioned, you need to change the `LoginManager.getInstance()` into `loginButton` and `setReadPermissions`, e.g.         `loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));`

Comment: No, I think that you can use either: `To respond to a login result, you need to register a callback with either LoginManager or LoginButton. ` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#callback_handling)